# Non-Concurrent builds using DevEnv.exe

Tags: visual-studio-2010, build, devenv

I have a requirement to use devenv.exe to build our VS2010 projects. I need the projects to build 1 at a time since running multiple builds concurrently causes issues. I have set the number of concurrent builds to 1 in Tools -> Options -> Projects & Solutions -> Build and Run. When I execute the build directly from VS2010 everything works ask expected.

```
------ Rebuild started: Project: project1, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
.
Compile Output
.
------ Rebuild started: Project: project2, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
.
Compile Output
.
```

But when I run it from the command line

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" C:\Users\Me\project\MySolution.sln /rebuild "Release|win32" /project C:\Users\Me\project\MyProject.vcxproj /out C:\DevEnv.log
```

It starts to the build the projects in parallel.

```
Microsoft (R) Visual Studio Version 10.0.30319.1. 
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp. All rights reserved.
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: project1, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
2>------ Rebuild All started: Project: project2, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
3>------ Rebuild All started: Project: project3, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
4>------ Rebuild All started: Project: project4, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
```

Is there a flag or setting that I am missing to get these builds to run 1 at a time when using the command line?

Edit: It should be noted that I am running this build in Jenkins. When running the above command in a command prompt it seems to work fine. But running the command in Jenkins causes the build to execute in parallel. Perhaps there is some environment variable that needs to be set?

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen anyone try to build a solution from the command line using devenv.exe.  I think that's because devenv.exe *is* Visual Studio.  You're probably better off using MSBuild instead.  Anything VS does MSBuild should be able to do because VS uses MSBuild under the hood.  And it should be able to build your solution and/or project files without modification.

Since you say you're using Jenkins for CI, check out this MSBuild plugin for Jenkins.

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/MSBuild+Plugin

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but as I said in the first line "I have a requirement to use devenv.exe to build our VS2010 projects." The issue with using MSBuild is the way it computes build order. Devenv just follows what was manually set in the solution file. MSBuild creates a dependency tree based on what is setup as dependencys in each project file then creates a build order based on that. The issue is we have projects that cannot be setup as direct dependencies of the projects we are trying to compile.